# Django migration giving errors

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, django-migrations, rdbms

In my Django Project, I have deleted a model, did `./manage.py makemigrations`

Now, when I was trying to do `./manage migrate`, I was getting error like

> TypeError: Field 'id' expected a number but got datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 16, 18, 18, 45, 598727, tzinfo=)

So, what I did was, went to POSTGRESQL and dropped the table (whose model I had deleted before) and ran migrate command again.

But again, I am getting the same error, I know that I have messed up the migrations, can someone please tell how to do successful migration?

Answer (score 1):

sometimes it's because of previous migration files that django make it by default. try to delete all migration files that django has made it in migrations file. then run makemigrations again.
If it didn't work, (I know it's cheap idea) drop database and then make it again.